Request for Review: First PCB Design - Feedback on Potential Issues or Missing Elements
I have recently designed my first PCB and I am seeking feedback on it to ensure there are no errors or missing elements. I have attached the schematic of my design. The PCB includes various components such as a STM32, a CAN transceiver, a TMC2209 driver, a 3.3V regulator, and other peripheral components.
Given that this is my first attempt at PCB design, I would appreciate any insights or suggestions from you to identify potential issues or improvements. Specifically, I am interested in feedback on the following aspects:
CAN Bus connection. is any thing missing? MCU to TMC2209 UART connection. Voltage regulator is it good enought? VCC_IN and Vm will be 20v.
Thank you in advance for your help! 
So far, I have completed the schematic design using my Altium. I have double checked the connections and ensured that all components are properly placed and connected according to their datasheets and application notes.
I expect the schematic to be free of any major errors and to be a solid foundation for creating the PCB layout.
However, since this is my first PCB design, I am uncertain if I have overlooked any critical aspects or made any mistakes. I have not yet proceeded to the PCB layout stage because I want to be sure that the schematic is correct and complete. Therefore, I am seeking feedback to identify any issues before moving forward.

How much current the circuit consumes? 150mA and the regulator is toast. Also we don't know what that design is supposed to do or what you expect it to do so it is difficult to assess if it does it or not.

Why is STM32F103 used because people mainly use it for USB and you are not using USB? Why is there a pull-up resistor on reset pin? Why the regulator 3.3V output supply seems unused, from where the 3.3V comes from? Why the SWD connector has no 3.3V for debugger VREF, does debugger assume always 3.3V supply? Does debugger work without reset pin too?

Similarly, what is the source for +Vin, the motor power supply? Is it supposed to be the same as Vcc, the input to the regulator? Altium has tools to help you find obvious errors like single-pin nets, or nets with no source.

Thanks for the comments.
I thought the regulator is rated for 500mA. The design is for a closed loop stepper motor where i want to monitor and correct position. There will five motors and a central node where the CAN will be used for communication.
Do you have any suggestion on MCU other than stm32f103?

Dave tweed. Yes motor power supply and +Vin and Vcc should be same. I will try to use the Altium tool. Thanks

The 78M33 is a low-power linear regulator. The amount of current it can deliver is a strong function of the input voltage, with the power dissipation being the limiting factor.

Ok, i understand now. Thank you

Remember decoupling on U4

Is it better to use TLV761 and drop the power supply voltage to 12v or use current regulator (78M33 ) with 12v. If I calculated correctly the circuit should consume between 100-150mA

Using net names to connect things (rather than "wires" makes it very difficult to follow signal flow so, I suggest that you avoid this method entirely.

Misc review remarks:

Depending on your BoM budget I'd use something more modern than SN65HVD232, although that might force you to also include a 5V regulator. I've used the one you've specified quite a lot and it works but the signals don't look ideal. Modern transceivers have better EMI characteristics and protection.

Since this CAN transceiver isn't as rugged as modern ones, consider adding external TVS on CANH + CANL.

It is generally recommended to put a common mode filter on CANH + CANL. There are special parts designed with CAN buses in mind for this.

The problem with spamming all decoupling caps on a long 3.3V line like you've done is that we have no idea which IC they belong to by reading the schematic. If instead placed next to the IC supply, we would know if you have remembered or forgotten decoupling caps.

A big bulk cap on the supply input never hurts, particularly not if you share the voltage line with a number of motors that may cause supply surges.

Is +Vm some 24VDC or such? You likely need TVS there.

As mentioned in comments, SWD connectors should have access to the supply. And usually also the reset line. Might want to consider some ESD counter-measures there like series resistors, depending on what speeds you plan to use.


